# C++ Class definition syntax

Tags: c++, class

when I tried to compile the following code I got an error:

> "include/IBCppClient/client/SoftDollarTier.h|3|error: variable
>   ‘TWSAPIDLLEXP SoftDollarTier’ has initializer but incomplete type|".

I guess the code is correct since it is part of a stock broker's API. But I struggle to understand the part on class definition `"class TWSAPIDLLEXP SoftDollarTier"`. As far as I know, this syntax is not legal in C++. What did I miss?

```
class TWSAPIDLLEXP SoftDollarTier{ 
std::string m_name, m_val, m_displayName;

public:
    SoftDollarTier(const std::string& name = "", const std::string& val = "", const std::string& displayName = "");

    std::string name() const;
    std::string val() const;
    std::string displayName() const;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ allows *macro definitions*, which allow the C preprocessor to essentially find-and-replace these macros with more elaborate definitions. A common practice in C/C++ is to insert function attributes before their names using preprocessor macros, and what likely happened is that your environment does not include the header file which defines `TWSAPIDLLEXP`, so the compiler interprets the string as the class name.

From a quick search, it seems that `TWSAPIDLLEXP` is defined in [tws-api](https://github.com/bianster/tws-api) (not sure if this is the same broker) as:

```
#define TWSAPIDLLEXP __declspec(dllimport)
```

in `IBJts/samples/Cpp/TestCppClient/StdAfx.h`.